# Simple data pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a query (select [type], a, b, c, d, e from MyTable) that returns:

```
[type], [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
type 1,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x
type 2,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x
type 3,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x ,  x
```

I'd like to pivot the data so it displays as:

```
[]     , [type 1], [type 2], [type 3] 
[a]    , x       , x       , x
[b]    , x       , x       , x
[c]    , x       , x       , x
[d]    , x       , x       , x 
[e]    , x       , x       , x
```

Any pointers on the SQL here would be appreciated.

Comment: The columns a,b,c,d,e are fixed but there could be X number of rows (types)

Comment: I just need to rotate the table, the data does not need grouping, i.e. the types in the [type] column will always be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need is:

```
SELECT  Col, [type 1], [type 2], [type 3]
FROM    (SELECT [type], Amount, Col
         FROM   (SELECT [type], [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
                FROM    _MyTable) as sq_source
                UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Col IN ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e])) as sq_up) as sq 
PIVOT (MIN(Amount) FOR [type] IN ([type 1], [type 2], [type 3])) as p;
```

But since the **types** number is undetermined, we have to do it dynamically

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)
SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + [type] + ']',
                         '[' + [type] + ']')
FROM    _MyTable
ORDER BY [type]

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @query = N'SELECT   Col, ' + @cols + '
FROM    (SELECT [type], Amount, Col
         FROM   (SELECT [type], [a], [b], [c], [d], [e]
                FROM    _MyTable) as sq_source
                UNPIVOT (Amount FOR Col IN ([a], [b], [c], [d], [e])) as sq_up) as sq 
PIVOT (MIN(Amount) FOR [type] IN (' + @cols + ')) as p;';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

But be careful, because this query is technically a vector for an injection.

Comment: It's worth noting that, even if you changed @cols and @query to be nvarchar(max), this will break for anything more than 4096 `types`. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want for now. I'll work on the injection issue later!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
create table #test
(
type varchar(10),
a varchar(10),
b varchar(10),
c varchar(10),
d varchar(10),
e varchar(10)
)

insert into #test values
('type 1',  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x'  , 'x'),
('type 2',  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x'),
('type 3',  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x' ,  'x')

select * from
(

   select * from
   (
      select * from #test
   )data_to_unpivot
   UNPIVOT
   (
   Orders FOR [xxx] IN (a,b,c,d,e)

   )UNPIVOTED_DATA 
)data_to_pivot
PIVOT
(
MAX(orders) for type in ([type 1],[type 2],[type 3])
)PIVOTED_DATA
```

Comment: This hard codes the types (type 1, type 2, type 3). I commented earlier that the types are variable.